# Port Forwarding on OpenWRT

Tags: linux, http, portforwarding, lighttpd, openwrt

Tried forwarding HTTP port to my linux desktop running lighttpd but it isn't working. Server is running perfectly, works with nginx also. I can access the page from localhost but not through my public IP.

**Firewall-Zone settings:**

| Zone > Forwardings | Input | Output | Forward |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lan > wan | accept | accept | accept |
| wan > reject | reject | accept | accept |

and **Port Forwarding Config :**

```
config redirect
        option dest 'lan'
        option target 'DNAT'
        option name 'HTTP'
        option src 'wan'
        option src_dport '80'
        option dest_port '80'
        option dest_ip '192.168.1.100'
```

Also here are the screenshots of current settings. What am I doing wrong?

[OpenWRT Firewall-Zone Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAbVq.png)

[OpenWRT Port Forwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZzdv.png)

Comment: @fahimscirex: You posted: "but it isn't working".  You'll have to do better than that in describing what *is* happening instead of saying only "it's not doing what I want it to do".  Is lighttpd running on your desktop?  Can you access lighttpd with a local request (from your desktop)?  Can you access lighttpd (on your desktop) from the router?  Is your upstream provider blocking or filtering external access to port 80?

Comment: @gstrauss i've updated the post. Yes lighttpd works fine from localhost also from other devices connected to my router. I'm not sure about the ISP part, few months before they were blocking ports globally but was accessible from nationwide connection, which isn't working either right now. I've tried asking about the issue but that didn't go well, how can I make sure if the issue is from my ISP's side without asking them?

Comment: "how can I..." same pattern as before.  You tested from your desktop (localhost), you tested from your router to your desktop.  Now test from your router to your desktop, but specify that your client, e.g. curl, should use a source IP on the router that it facing your ISP, i.e. the IP on the router that is on the WAN side, outside your network.  `man curl` and look at `--interface`.  Beyond that, there are numerous sites on the internet that you can find in a search engine and which will try to connect to a given host.  That might help you troubleshoot further.